# NodeJS: Command line redirection to log files is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, command-line

I run my ***nodejs*** server on the *command line* like this: I send all the `console.log` messages to ***info.log*** and `console.error` messages to ***error.log***

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" Z:\application\server.js > info.log 2> error.log
```

My server is running and showing a bunch of logs on the terminal. But why is there no log file being created?

I have searched both `Z:\application` and `C:\Program Files\nodejs` directories. They do not have these log files.

Any help would be invaluable.

Comment: You might need to run the server as an administrator since changing files in C drive in windows usually requires admin privileges.

Comment: @DavidChristie I have tried running the command line in administrator mode. It's still not working.